# separate too long words in string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String with some text, f.e.
"Thisisalongwordtest and I want tocutthelongword in pieces"

Now I want to cut the to longs word in 2 pieces with a blank. The word should be cut if it's longer than 10 characters.

The result should be:
"Thisisalon gwordtest and I want tocutthelo ngword in pieces"

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: There are cases which you didn't explain how should be handled, for instance do you also want to separate something like `foobarbazz.` to `foobarbazz .`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for this? or I misunderstood the question?

```
String newString = oldStr.replaceAll("\\w{10}","$0 "))
```

with your example, the `newString` is:

```
Thisisalon gwordtest and I want tocutthelo ngword in pieces
```

#### Edit for Pshemo's good comment

to avoid to add space after words with exact 10 chars:

```
str.replaceAll("\\w{10}(?=\\w)","$0 "));
```

Comment: This will add space also after exactly ten letter words. Maybe add `(?!\\s)` at the end of your regex. Also we don't know how to handle `.` `!` `?` and other characters, for instance if `10charWord.` should be replaced with `10charWord .` or not. Or based on that how to handle `foo.................bar`?

Comment: @Pshemo good point, I added a new line in answer.

Comment: @Pshemo regarding the definition of "word", if OP gave the specified rule, we could use `[.....]`.

Comment: Your edit will consume next character so now regex will not be able to use it in next match so using it on `012345678901234567890123456789` will produce `0123456789 01234567890 123456789` and as you see second word is `01234567890` which has 11 characters. It is better to use look-around mechanisms here since they are zero-width.

Comment: @Pshemo you are right, I tried to avoid to use look ahead, but apparently, it didn't work. I added `(?=\\w)`

Comment: Actually my first suggestion `(?!\\s)` was wrong because it didn't handle case where 10 character word would be placed at the end of text so it should be either `(?!\\s|$)` or `(?=\\S)` or `(?=\\w)` depending on what OP wants. UPDATE: I see you updated your answer, now it can be easily adapted to OP needs +1.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot, that looks good. But its not working for me, but this is my fault. \w does not include special characters like + or / and so on, or am i wrong? the string has those character because some guys like headlines like "SPECIAL++OFFER-BEST++PRICE/DEAL"

Comment: @user3876178 as I commented, put those letters that you need in `[..]`

Comment: I need every Letter/Character except blank/space

Comment: @user3876178 then use `\\S`

Answer (score 2):

```
.replaceAll("(\\w{10})(?=\\w)", "$1 ")
```

[Tested with](http://ideone.com/Nb37pw):

```
test("abcde fghij klmno pqrst");
test("abcdefghijklmnopqrst");
test("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv");
test("abcdefghij klmnopqrstuv");
test("abcdefghij klmnopqrst uv");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  (?=\w{10,}\s)(\w{10})
```

Should be replaced by

```
 "\1 "
```

you can use replace function.

If it has number or special characters

```
(?=\S{10,}\s)(\S{10})
```

can be used.

Comment: I think your solution adds a useless space after words of exactly 10 characters

Comment: Could you elaborate, how to combine RegExp and replace function?

Comment: @Volune thanx for that.Now its corrected.

Answer (score 1):

- separate text into words. (by space)
- cut long words and replace source word with new words
- assemble text again

Note, that this approach will kill multiple-spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i wrote check it once.....

```
    public class TakingInput {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     String s="Thisisalongwordtest and I want tocutthelongword in pieces";

     StringBuffer sb;

     String arr[]=s.split(" ");

     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

        if(arr[i].length()>10){

            sb=new StringBuffer(arr[i]);

            sb.insert(10," ");

            arr[i]=new String(sb);

        }

     }

     for(String ss: arr){

         System.out.println(ss);//o/p: "Thisisalon gwordtest and I want tocutthelo ngword in pieces"

     }



}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will do exactly what you want.

First create a method that splits a `String` if its longer than 10 `char`s:

```
String splitIfLong(String s){
    if(s.length() < 11) return s + " ";
    else{
        String result = "";
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            temp += s.charAt(i);
            if(i == 9)
                temp += " ";
                result += temp;
                temp = "";
        }
        return result + " ";
    }
}
```

Then use `Scanner` to read every word in the sentence seperated by a white space`" "`:

```
String s = "Thisisalongwordtest and I want tocutthelongword in pieces";

String afterSplit = "";

Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
```

Then call the `splitIfLong()` method for every word in the sentence. And add what the method returns to a new `String`:

```
while(in.hasNext())
        afterSplit += splitIfLong(in.next());
```

Now you can use the new `String` as you wish. If you call:

`System.out.println(afterSplit);`

it will print:

`Thisisalon gwordtest and I want tocutthelo ngword in pieces`

Hope this helps